# OneHotEncoder ValueError: Found unknown categories

Tags: scikit-learn, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding, feature-engineering

I am building the OneHotEncoder using the full file.

```
def buildOneHotEncoder(training_file_name, categoricalCols):
    one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)

    df = pd.read_csv(training_file_name, skiprows=0, header=0)
    df = df[categoricalCols]
    df = removeNaN(df, categoricalCols)
    logging.info(str(df.columns))
    one_hot_encoder.fit(df)
    return one_hot_encoder
```

```
def removeNaN(df, categoricalCols):
    # Replace any NaN values
    for col in categoricalCols:
        df[[col]] = df[[col]].fillna(value=CONSTANT_FILLER)
    return df
```

Now i am using this same encoder when i processing the same file in chunks

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv(training_file_name, chunksize=CHUNKSIZE):
....
  INPUT = chunk[categoricalCols]
  INPUT = removeNaN(INPUT, categoricalCols)
  one_hot_encoded = one_hot_encoder.transform(INPUT)
....
```

It's giving me error 'ValueError: Found unknown categories ['missing'] in column 2 during transform'

I can't process the full file at once as during training iterations memory is required to use all cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with applying

```
df_merged_set_test = chunk.where(chunk['weblab']=="missing")
```

I was filtering the dataset based on the a field so for the all rows which are it fill NaN. I was later on replacing them with a missing flag.

The correct way

1. Clean the dataset i.e fill all na values for all columns
2. Then filter and drop NaN rows i.e all values NaN rows `.where(chunk['weblab']=="missing").dropna()`

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to initialize [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) with `handle_unknown=` parameter:

```py
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean data from any nan data.
The following code show you the count of nan data for each column

```
total_missing_data = data.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
percent_of_missing_data = (data.isnull().sum()/data.isnull().count()*100).sort_values(ascending=False)
missing_data = pd.concat(
    [
        total_missing_data, 
        percent_of_missing_data
    ], 
    axis=1, 
    keys=['Total', 'Percent']
)
print(missing_data.head(10))
```

output such as:

```
Total   Percent
```

age 2   0.284091

To get it is location:
`df.loc[(data['age'].isnull())]`

Then fill nan column using mean or meadiean:

```
df.age[62]=data.age.median()
```

or drop all nan rows:

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: This is bad advice